# Why do I get " stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not tuple" type error?

Tags: python, string, os.path, file-move

I am trying to group files into folders based on the prefix of the filename. Error:     os.stat(path)

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not tuple

I am getting the error on the line that corresponds to `dir_path = file[:-8]`

```
import os
import pickle
from os.path import join, exists
import shutil 


RootDir = r'D:\Folder'

count = 0
for file in os.walk((os.path.normpath(RootDir)), topdown=False):
    dir_path = file[:-8]
  
    if not os.path.exists(dir_path):
        os.makedirs(dir_path)
        
    if os.path.exists(dir_path):
        shutil.move(file)
```

Any insights as to where I did it wrong? Thank you.

Comment: try to debug by printing "file" variable and dir_path variable, and validate values against your actual files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line to `dir_path = file[0][:-8]`.
According to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), `os.walk()` yields a tuple: `(dirpath, dirnames, filenames)`, therefore `file` in your code is a tuple containing dirpath, dirnames, and filenames.